Getting Error While Installing wdm (0.1.1) With RubyGems On Windows 11
I was trying to install wdm ~> 0.1.1 with gem 3.5.11 on Windows 11 and getting this error:
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/willi/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing wdm:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Users/willi/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/ext/wdm
D:/Chocolatey/lib/ruby.install/tools/True/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for -lkernel32... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for ruby.h... yes
checking for HAVE_RUBY_ENCODING_H... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Users/willi/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/ext/wdm
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240628-26536-1pbxw8 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240628-26536-1pbxw8 clean

current directory: C:/Users/willi/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1/ext/wdm
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240628-26536-1pbxw8 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240628-26536-1pbxw8
generating wdm_ext-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
compiling entry.c
compiling memory.c
compiling monitor.c
compiling queue.c
compiling rb_change.c
rb_change.c: In function 'extract_absolute_path_from_notification':
rb_change.c:139:5: warning: 'RB_OBJ_TAINT' is deprecated: taintedness turned out to be a wrong idea. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  139 |     OBJ_TAINT(path);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from D:/Chocolatey/lib/ruby.install/tools/True/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/core/rstring.h:30,
                 from D:/Chocolatey/lib/ruby.install/tools/True/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/arithmetic/char.h:29,
                 from D:/Chocolatey/lib/ruby.install/tools/True/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/arithmetic.h:24,
                 from D:/Chocolatey/lib/ruby.install/tools/True/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:28,
                 from D:/Chocolatey/lib/ruby.install/tools/True/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby.h:38,
                 from wdm.h:22,
                 from rb_change.c:4:
D:/Chocolatey/lib/ruby.install/tools/True/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/internal/fl_type.h:824:1: note: declared here
  824 | RB_OBJ_TAINT(VALUE obj)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compiling rb_monitor.c
rb_monitor.c: In function 'rb_monitor_run_bang':
rb_monitor.c:509:29: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_thread_call_without_gvl' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  509 |         waiting_succeeded = rb_thread_call_without_gvl(wait_for_changes, monitor->process_event, stop_monitoring, monitor);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:248: rb_monitor.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/willi/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/wdm-0.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/willi/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/wdm-0.1.1/gem_make.out


I've tried to reinstall RubyGem with Devkit.
I have MSYS64 properly installed in C:\.
I've run ridk install.
I tried to install in admin mode but nothing works.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Problem solved I used gem install wdm -- --with-cflags=-Wno-implicit-function-declaration
